# CocoaPods: Unable to find a specification for `TestFlightSDK (= 3.0.0)`

Tags: ios, cocoapods, testflight

I'm trying to do

> pod install

and I get the following error:

> [!] Unable to find a specification for `TestFlightSDK (= 3.0.0)`

I tried

> pod update

and I get the same error:

> [!] Unable to find a specification for `TestFlightSDK (= 3.0.0)`

Why is this occurring?

I tried the following and still getting error:

> pod repo remove master
>
> pod setup

I also did a

> $pod repo list

and got:

> master
>   - Type: git (master)
>
> - URL:  https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
>
> - Path: /Users/myUser/.cocoapods/repos/master

I then did a

> $ pod search TestFlightSDK

and it could not the pod:

> [!] Unable to find a pod with name matching `TestFlightSDK'

Comment: I see the same results here. Maybe the pod has been removed since the transfer to Apple, and the CocoaPods website just hasn't been updated?

Comment: @Luke definitely seems to be the case, see my answer, although the pod is still listed on CocoaPods.org the **Podspec** link is no longer available (404).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering this on my own until I see a better answer:
According to the following article, [Testflight shutdown and incorporated with iTunes connect](http://9to5mac.com/2015/01/26/apple-legacy-testflight-shutdown) or [you can read it here straight from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/update/).

Comment: If your going to down-vote at least post a reason for down-voting, so I can update the answer

Answer (score 0):

This pod is related to the **old** TestFlight, which was shut down after it's aquisition by Apple.

If you check the pod's page on cocoapods.org at https://cocoapods.org/?q=TestFlightSDK you can see that the **Homepage** links to http://www.testflightapp.com/, which is the old TestFlight website and is now redirected to Apple's new TestFlight intro site.

Additionally if you try to open the **See Podspec** link ( https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/TestFlightSDK/3.0.2/TestFlightSDK.podspec.json ) it's now a GitHub 404 page.

The new, Apple TestFlight service does not have an SDK yet.

Comment: Please if the new, Apple TestFlight service does not have an SDK yet, so how can we add it into the project?

Comment: @Llg you don't - the Apple TestFlight service doesn't have an SDK so you can't integrate into your project.

Comment: @Llg what you can do is to use either the TestFlight web UI manually, or use a tool like `fastlane` or https://www.bitrise.io/cli to automate the uploads etc

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. My problem is that I have an old project and I'm trying now to build/ run it. The project was using TestFlight in many parts of the code like this `[TestFlight passCheckpoint:@"screenName"]`. I was looking for adding it via pods, but since there is no SDK I don't know how I can manage this.

Comment: Ahh, makes sense @Llg . Unfortunately I think your only option is to remove the TestFlight pod and codes from the project, as the new TestFlight is nothing like the old / non Apple one was, pretty much the only thing carried over was the name. All the services, SDK etc. provided by the non Apple TestFlight were discontinued / removed / shut down.